# Replacing a section of text in one file with text from another using python

Tags: python

First a bit of background: yes, I am new to python, but I like to dabble and learn things.

The goal is this: I have an intranet website here at work and they have us on a static server with no server side scripting allowed, meaning no PHP. So as I add new pages, I must update every freakin page's menu with the new link. Fortunately, I have an application called ArcGIS installed on my computer and with it came an installation of python. So I was thinking it would be nice to just put together a script that would read a file called "menu.txt" and then search recursively in my directory (and subdirectories) for files with ".html" and replace all text between some comment tags, like `<!--begin menu-->` and `<!--end menu-->`, with the text in "menu.txt"

So I started looking and found this snippet of code:

```
with open('menu.txt', 'r') as f:
    # read entire file into file1
    # ASSUMING 'file1.txt' is relatively small...
    file1 = f.read()

with open('test.html', 'r') as f:
    # ASSUMING 'file2.txt' is relatively small...
    file2 = f.read()    # read file into file2

# index() will raise an error if not found...
f1_start = file1.index('<!--123-->')
f1_end = file1.index('<!--321-->', f1_start)     # look for '//end' after '//start'

f2_start = file2.index('<!--123-->')
f2_end = file2.index('<!--321-->', f2_start)

# replace file2 lines with proper file1 lines
file2[f2_start:f2_end] = file1[f1_start:f1_end]

with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(file2)
```

and I've also seen many examples using `re`, `replace` and such, but nothing that seems to be related to what i need. Anyway, right now I'm just trying it on the one file in the same directory, but when I run this on either my linux machine or in a windows python shell I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\webpages\filereplace.py", line 18, in <module>
    file2[f2_start:f2_end] = file1[f1_start:f1_end]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I thought the problem might've been the `with open` part, but I don't know.

In this case the contents of menu.txt are essentially a beginning comment tag `<!--123-->`, then all of the `<div id=menu>blah blah blah</div>`, then an end comment tag `<!--321-->`. In my html file, I use the same comment tags, and you get the picture...

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are familiar with PHP (which is what it sounds like), why not simply write your site as though server-side scripting were possible, then simply run through each page and take the generated output as static pages?

Comment: 'str' type in python is immutable, which means you can't do certain operations/changes on it. What you can do is make your file1,file2 as a list, and using your same code to make changes, and convert back to string.

Comment: file.read() loads your file into a string and you can't replace parts of the string with []. You might try [str.replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace).

Comment: Ok, I'm intrigued. Though maybe not as handy with PHP as it might appear. I do know how to use a "<?php include(); ?>" in my files, so I can use one menu.php and have it update across the entire site, but I'm not sure what you mean by "simply run through each page and take the generated output as static pages". It seems like you understand that I don't have PHP on this server, so I don't know...

Comment: What makes you think the problem is in the `with open` part? The traceback shows where the actual problem is, and it's nowhere near there, doesn't involve the `f` variables, etc.

Comment: Nevermind that, I was tripping on something I read when I saw this code... :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, when dealing with in-place editing of files, I turn to the `fileinput` module:

```
import os
import fileinput

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Menu should not have any marker, just pure contents
    with open('menu.txt') as f:
        menu_contents = f.read()

    # Initialize a few items
    start_marker = '<!--123-->'
    end_marker   = '<!--321-->'
    file_list = ['index.html', 'foo.html']
    found_old_contents = False

    # Loop to replace text in place
    for line in fileinput.input(file_list, inplace=True):
        line = line.rstrip()

        if line == start_marker:
            found_old_contents = True
            print line
            print menu_contents
        elif line == end_marker:
            found_old_contents = False

        if not found_old_contents:
            print line
```

#### Discussion

The key here is in the function `fileinput.input(file_list, inplace=True)`, which takes a list of file names, iterates through them line-by-line, and writes back to the files whatever you `print` out.

You will need to come up with a list of files (e.g. `file_list`) by means of `os.walk()` or some other methods.

I have tested my code against two .html files and confident that it works. I cannot guaranty the results, especially for nested directories. Good luck.

Comment: Well, this one gives me a syntax error on "print line" with line highlighted in red. All I did was change the file name from index.html to test.html. Hmmm...

Comment: What version of Python are you using? If you use version 3.x, then change it to `print(line)`

Comment: Well, this works! Funny thing, it just so happens that this GIS mapping software that I have, comes with python 2.5 sort of embedded in it. Well, wanting to be all up to date, I installed python 3.3. Now as I was navigating the directory I inadvertently just double clicked my .py file and it worked! Then I realized that it must've defaulted to the 2.5. I was getting the syntax error only when using the 3.3 shell. So now I guess I'll test the newer print(line) and see how it goes and I'll start putting nested files in the file_list... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to modify a string in-place. This is not possible in python, because strings are immutable.

To achieve what you want, you would need create a new string from the parts of existing two strings:

```
# replace file2 lines with proper file1 lines
new_f = file2[:f2_start] + file1[f1_start:f1_end] + file2[f2_end:]
```

After that, write the contents to the file like so:

```
with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_f)
```

Also, note that variable names `file1` and `file2` are a bit misleading here, as these are not file-like objects, but strings.

Comment: Ok, so I adjusted the code and changed the names: # replace old_menu lines with proper new_menu lines
new_f = old_menu[:m2_start] + new_menu[m1_start:m1_end] + old_menu[m2_end:], it does to something to the test.html file, but no changes are evident. I'm not sure if I should reference new_f when I do the write(old_menu) part? Well, I tried that too and still no luck...

Comment: I edited the answer to make it more clear: your new content is stored in the variable `new_f`.

Comment: Well thanks also! It works too! Right now, I'm exploring the other answer because of the list capabilities. I guess eventually I'll be exploring having it just recursively go through my directories and subdirectories and making the changes without having to include them in the list.... or maybe just build a list based on ".html" and the work the changes. Hmmmm.... Either way, for my first time on Stackoverflow, this is pretty awesome!